# Cant load webpack 2 external library with dot notation

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I have the following webpack 2 config set for an external library:

```
externals: {
    "importnameoflibrary": { root: "library.component" }
    ...
}
```

This attempts to load the following (which doesnt work because of the dot notation:

```
root["library.component"]
```

However, what I need it to do is this (which works):

```
root["library"]["component"] or root.library.component
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array for the value:

```
externals: {
    "importnameoflibrary": { root: ["library", "component"] }
    ...
}
```